# Can someone explain to me exactly what part of this is patentable?

Tags: patentability, us20130233002

In reference to the patent: [US 2013/0233002 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130233002)

Can someone explain to me exactly what part of this is patentable?

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the Image File Wrapper `Notice of Allowance and Fees Due (PTOL-85)` on the [Public Pair](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) system, you'll find that the original claims were rejected (obvious, not novel and anticipated by prior art). During an April 20, 2015 telephone interview with the examiner, the following single claim (Claim 19, emended) was allowed. The patent issued on July 8, 2015 with this single claim:

```
A device comprising:
  a chest for containing a quantity of liquid;
  a lid for the chest defining an airway and having a radiator in the airway for chilling air and a fan that moves the air through the airway and out of the lid; and
  a pump in the insulated chest that moves liquid from the chest, through the radiator, and back to the chest. the chest having upper shell and lower shell;
  a power supply operatively coupled to the fan and the pump;
  a flexible portion of airway that is manipulable by a user to change a location where chilled air exits the lid;
  wherein the upper shell and lower shell define two air shafts with [[a]]the user manipulable flexible vent tube therebetween.
```